Using [MemberNotNull] in a virtual override that is called in BaseClass constructor
I have the following code Try it here
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
    
public class Base{
    protected Base(){
        Initialize();
    }
    
    protected virtual void Initialize(){}
}


public class Derived : Base{
    public string _someString;
    
    public Derived() : base(){
    }
    
    [MemberNotNull(nameof(_someString))]
    protected override void Initialize(){
        _someString = "Test";
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}

I'm still getting the warning

/home/Program.cs(16,9): warning CS8618: Non-nullable field '_someString' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the field as nullable. [/home/home.csproj]

Now clearly this field will be fully initialized. However the compiler doesn't realise it. Is there a way to make it understand?
The motivation for this is that Derived is a generated partial class I want the extra members to be automatically initialized. If I just call "Initialize()" directly in the Derived constructor, the warnings disappear, but I want to avoid this step.

Doesn't this produce another warning about calling virtual members in a ctor? => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2214

I rather suspect that there's no direct workaround here: I'm not aware of any way to tell the compiler that base() will always result in Initialize being called. You might have to do the workaround of public string _someString = null!;

@Fildor neither in the above link nor my local system... However your link contains an interesting point: When a virtual method is called, the actual type that executes the method is not selected until run time. This kind of hints that Roslyn can't know what would happen.

The warning is not enabled by default, but will be raised depending on what static analysers you're using. You generally want to avoid doing that (call virtual members in constructor) because even if you know the code now is fine, later changes may exhibit unexpected behaviour.

And I am sure I had a resource with some alternatives to fix that ... but I can't seem to find it ...

It's hard to say without knowing exactly what your generator is doing, but suggestions would be: get the generator to initialise new fields in line, generate the call to initialise in the derived constructor. Suppressing the warning(s) and/or using the null-forgiving operator both raise the risk of later changes causing problems, but as it's generated code that is less of an issue

@iakobski can't do it inline, since it needs a reference to the calling class. GeneratedProperty = new(this);

I'm missing something... isn't that an infinite loop?

This is essentially a bad design. You should never call a non-sealed virtual method from a constructor.

@iakobski no, why would it be? Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean with inline.

@Matthew Watson, yeah I gathered this from the responses and have since changed my code to manually call "Initialize()" in every function. It's a bit cumbersome, but meh, it works.

I found my internal article but unfortunately, the solution is not applicable here. It referenced this article: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/VirtualMemberCallInConstructor.html and this post from Eric Lippert.

@infinitezero I assumed that line is the real one in the Initialise() method - so in effect you're calling the this constructor from within the constructor?

^^ Main takeaway was (citation) "Such virtual method, in fact, should be a pure function that returns some value and doesn't depend on the stateof the derived type. If this is the case, make such function static (since it is pure) and pass its return value to the base type as a parameter to protected constructor.".

@iakobski You can't do this: public class Test{ GeneratedType Prop = new(this); }. But you can do this: public class Test{ GeneratedType Prop; void Initialize(){Prop = new(this);} there is no additional constructor calling.

Prop = new(this); could also be done in a generated ctor, no? If you can generate an Initialize method with it, you should be able to gen a ctor with it, I would guess.

Ah - penny drops, GeneratedProperty is of another type. Thanks.

@Fildor I can surely generate a ctor. But then I would need to call the ctor, so where is the difference to calling the initialize method? My class needs to do other stuff than just initializing the generated properties.

What I meant was: you could ditch the virtual Initialize method, in favor of generated CTORs, which are called, anyway.

After a little bit of experimenting... how about something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/37HygA ( utilizing a Factory method ) ?
